# IIS Autorisation doesn't detect NTFS Autorisation for my pool

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to host a WebApp (DotNet Core 3.1) on my new Windows 10 Machine.

I've created an AppPool => TestDeployPool (No Managed Code) => Started it

[image]

Then, I've granted TestDeployPool total permission over my puplish folder.

[image]

But when i try to test the site, I'm getting this warning that it doesn't have access to physical path!

[image]

I'm not sure where is my error for in authorisation tests to pass result.

Comment: Ignore the last dialog, which is totally useless for your setup. Move on and test your web app.

Comment: It doesn't work, it say 500.19 error (Invalid XML) because it doesn't have access to it

Comment: i was missing the Window Hosting bundle and i still have the error about autorisation. My app is now running but with error that i need to find out :)

Comment: That dialog only reports back a meaningful check when your virtual directory is mapped to something remote. It almost always gives you the authorization error and everyone should learn to ignore.

Comment: Yea, you were right, the real problem were the Windows Hosting Bundle was not installed!